# How to assign BooleanField's icons to IntegerField in Django

Tags: python, django, model

I have several (>20) fields with similar possible values and a choices set for them im my Model:

```
predicate_choices = ((0, True),
                     (1, False),
                     (2, 'someParam2'),
                     (3, 'someParam3'),)
field1 = models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=predicate_choices, verbose_name='field1')
field2 = models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=predicate_choices, verbose_name='field2')
field3 = models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=predicate_choices, verbose_name='field3')
```

My question is how I can display `0` and `1` values as those nice BooleanField icons? The are displayed as strings `True` and `False` at the moment.
As far as I found out, I need to set the `.boolean` property of a field to `True`, but just didn't manage to do that.
These fields are of integer type in the database itself, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

If you check at the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield), `BooleanField` uses a default `CheckboxInput` widget. So in your `IntegerField` you should define a widget attribute as a `CheckboxInput`.

Comment: Okay, so it did add a checkbox in "Add/Edit" form, but in the table itself it is still displayed as strings.